# react--dom patch is not detected. React 16.6+ features may not work

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

In Gatsby development, I get this error.

```
React-Hot-Loader: react--dom patch is not detected. React 16.6+ features may not
work.
```

Seems to be a none breaking error, but is there a way to remove it from the console?

Answer (score 6):

Oh man... There's a workaround in this [issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11934#issuecomment-469046186)

TL;DR

`npm install -D @hot-loader/react-dom`

In `gatsby-node.js` add the following:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ getConfig, stage }) => {
  const config = getConfig()
  if (stage.startsWith('develop') && config.resolve) {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11934#issuecomment-538662592), it's better to use `actions.setWebpackConfig` because it automatically merges with the default config:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, actions }) => {
  if (stage.startsWith("develop")) {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          "react-dom": "@hot-loader/react-dom",
        },
      },
    })
  }
}
```